# working with CRUD-app in netbeans IDE

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

Hi I'm new to NetBeans IDE. I have developed a basic desktop application with two textFields, one for `userName` and one for `password`. It also has an OK-Button. This app checks the username and password from the database.

Now I have added a Master/Detail sample form to that packet. Now the application works like this: it checks the userName and password when you click the OK button. If correct it runs the CRUD-app and here is where I experience a problem: the Master/Detail sample form runs and does not show on the screen. My question is how do I make it Visible?

---

Okay- I have created ths to call the CRUD-app which I named BB:

```
 OK.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
BB call= new BB();//Here I call the crude
```

### Call.setVisible(true);

It is: public class BB extents Jpanel{// class name

And I did try to use BB.show(); an I got an error saying: non static mrthod show() cannot be referenced fron a static cotext.
Even setVisible(true) doesn't show tha application

Comment: If you would make some code visible to us, maybe we can help you.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @MattHandy The problem with 'some code' is that often the OP does not know which code is actually relevant to the problem.  It might be better for the OP to factor out the DB and first check they can get any new (hard-coded if need be) data to appear in a GUI.  If they fail at that, in code of <50 lines, that would make a nice SSCCE.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Your example...

```
BB call= new BB();//Here I call the crude
Call.setVisible(true);
```

Did you copy and paste it or type it in? If you copied it, your problem is that you're not calling `setVisible` the right object. It should be...

```
BB call= new BB(); 
call.setVisible(true);  // Notice 'c' instead of 'C'
```

If that's not the problem, then what class does BB extend?  So, in the file BB.java there should be a line like this...

```
public class BB extends ???
```

Near the top of the file. What comes after the word `extends` in your file?